# Problem with restoring MySQL database - mysqldump question

Tags: passwords, mysql, mysql-error-1049

I made a backup of `my_database` like this:

```
mysqldump --add-drop-database --databases 
          --user=my_username --password=my_password my_database > backup.sql
```

Then I deleted the database completely, and tried to restore it like this:

```
mysql --user=my_username --password=my_password my_database < backup.sql
```

I got the following error:

```
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'my_database'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I need to be able to restore the database if it was changed somehow or removed completely.

Bonus question: is that possible to read the password from a file rather than providing it in the command line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are doing, then you do not need a 'database' argument for the 'mysql' invocation, since the dump should contain the `create database` statements.

As for the bonus: you want a `--defaults-extra-file` option

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqldump` command does not include the `create database` statement in its output. You need to create the `my_database` database before running the second command.

Comment: Au contraire, it most definitely does include the `create database` statement. Did you try it?

Comment: White: Please read carefully through the mysqldump invocation in the question and the excerpt from mysqldump documentation in your comment. As a matter of fact, I've just run mysqldump in the very same way, as done in the question. `create database` statement is there. Am I dreaming?

Comment: @skylent, You're right, I didn't see that the OP had included the --databases flag, which causes the `create database` statement to be included. It is worth noting that the `create database` statement is NOT included unless --databases or --all-databases is used.